# XSL OnChange Javascript Function not Defined

Tags: javascript, xslt, onchange

If I select anything from dropdown menu, javascript function showLeague is not called and throws an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: showLeague is not defined

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output
    method="html"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    indent="yes"></xsl:output>
<xsl:param name="tsid" /> 


<xsl:template match="spocosy">      

    <form>
    Select a League:

    <select>
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="cds"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="onchange">
        showLeague(this.value)
    </xsl:attribute>


    <option value="">Leagues:</option>
    <xsl:for-each select="standing">
    <option>
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@league"/>
    </option>
    </xsl:for-each>  
    </select>
    </form>

    <div id="txtHint"><b>League info will be listed here...</b></div>
</xsl:template>
```

showLeague function is defined in the head tag and without xsl it is working without any problem. Any help would be appreciated. If you want to observe html output here is the url: http://tipslator.com/Table/deneme/

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: should I post the complete code regarding this issue?

Comment: Try to isolate the problem to a minimal but complete sample, then post it. Or post a URL where we can visit the problem.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I hope, I understood you right, I paste the whole xsl code and url, so you can reach everything regarding this issue.

Comment: There is an iframe in that page with the result of the XSLT it seems, that iframe does not define any script functions to why do you expect the function to be available?

Comment: thank you so much, I didn't know that If you use Iframe it is completely independent from the main html. If you write it as answer I can vote it as correct

Comment: I wrote an answer pointing out that the iframe does not define any function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document http://tipslator.com/Table/deneme/ contains an iframe http://tipslator.com/xsl/getleaguename.php with a HTML document which seems to be the XSLT result. That iframe document does not define any script function at all so any call to a function will give an error, unless you make sure the functions are defined in the iframe (or you call up `parent.functionName` to call functions define in the parent window).